# How can I remove the "symbol" element from a SVG but preserve the "path" element (in bulk)? The Equivalent to "Break Link" in Illustrator

Tags: command-line, svg

Example SVG:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    class="mds-icon mds-doc-icon-swatch__icon" width="15" height="15">
    <defs>
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 15 15" id="sector-financial-services--s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
                d="M8 9.041a1.125 1.125 0 1 1-1.125-1.125A1.127 1.127 0 0 1 8 9.041zm1.875-6.125A1.125 1.125 0 1 0 11 4.041a1.127 1.127 0 0 0-1.125-1.125zM14 .833v13H1v-13zm-1 4h-1.157a2.125 2.125 0 1 0-3.937 0H4v4h.771a2.071 2.071 0 0 0-.021.208 2.108 2.108 0 0 0 .157.792H3v-4H2v5h3.744a2.106 2.106 0 0 0 1.131.333c.049 0 .1-.011.143-.014a1.482 1.482 0 0 0-.018.181 1.5 1.5 0 1 0 2.908-.5H12v-1H8.843A2.108 2.108 0 0 0 9 9.041a2.071 2.071 0 0 0-.021-.208H13z">
            </path>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#sector-financial-services--s" fill="#5E5E5E">

        <title>sector-financial-services--s</title>

    </use>
</svg>
```

I want to "de-nest" the symbol, so that the path data is outside of the `<defs>` node. I'm not sure how to do this... I've just been using illustrator and then clicking on `Break Link` at the top:

[image]

But I have about 200 SVGs to do this to. Is there a setting/flag for SVGO that will do this? A command-line tool?

The reason I'm doing this is because the SVGs are rendering as complete black boxes. When I click on `Break Link` and save, the SVG renders properly.

Any help extremely appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SVGs, but if it's as simple as you're claiming, so moving the `path` node to the main node, then a simple PowerShell script should suffice, e.g. `Get-ChildItem` -> `Get-Content` -> few XML processing functions.